# Multiple JAX-RS applications

Tags: servlets, cxf, jax-rs

I have specified my JAX-RS Application in the web.xml as follows:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>     
<servlet-class>
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
<param-value>
com.myapp.MYRestApplication       
</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Is it possible for me to pass another JAX-RS application class to this CXF servlet?

Regards,
Anand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While CXF can manage multiple JAX-RS applications within a single servlet — I use this configuration in my own code — it is sufficiently complex that you're far better off switching to using a Spring-based configuration. The `CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet` can only support limited configuration. In my code, I have this (a little complex because I'm also using Spring security, but you can drop that filter):

```xml
<!-- Location of the main Spring/CXF configuration file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Apply Spring Security as a wrapper to everything --> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Hook for Spring lifecycle management; you want this -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- A single servlet to handle all CXF processing -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: The main reason for having two different JAX-RS services within a single CXF container is so that you can have different mappings between web content (XML, JSON, etc.) and Java. That's _incredibly useful_, but not something that can be auto-configured safely. You might as well bite the bullet and go to using Spring.

Comment: Thanks for the response Donal. I'll try the spring approach. But this requirement was driven because of integration issues. We are trying to integrate another component into our web application. Both of us use apache CXF, but have our own Jax RS application class where we maintain our resources. I was looking for a way to seamlessly integrate their resources into our web app, while ensuring that we both continue working independently on our services. I hope I was able to convey what I meant to say.

Comment: And I'm guessing, even with the spring approach, both components (mentioned above) will have to modify the bean. xml to manage their resources? Is there a way to maintain independent configuration of resources/jax-rs applications, and integrating them together seamlessly within the web app project?

Comment: You can drive most of the Spring configuration out of annotations if you prefer — it's not my favorite method, but it works fine — but the connecting up of CXF to your code is best done in XML config. You'd do that in the `beans.xml` (referenced by `contextConfigLocation`) and that can easily include other Spring XML config files allowing you to keep virtually all config separated out nicely. The only awkward bit is if you have one sub-webapp dealing with URLs that are prefixes of the path handled by another.

Comment: I dealt with that in my code by having no prefixes _except_ for the root, which had a special very dumb webapp that just served up a general help page. It's declaration is `<jaxrs:server id="root_REST" address="/"><jaxrs:serviceBeans><ref bean="root_facade" /></jaxrs:serviceBeans><jaxrs:properties><entry key="org.apache.cxf.endpoint.private" value="true" /></jaxrs:properties></jaxrs:server>` (it's implementation is totally trivial so it interferes with nothing).

Comment: The code in question is open source so I can [point to it](http://code.google.com/p/taverna/source/browse/taverna/products/uk.org.taverna.server/tags/server-2.2a1) just fine, but it's also _very_ complicated in other parts so you'll probably find it more confusing than anything. :-)

Comment: Does not answer the question of how to do this with `CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet`.